# Place multiple Stop Orders (Long and Short) with TP&SL at the same time without overwriting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

Here's what I'm trying:

1. I want to place a Short and Long Stop Order at the same time.
2. If the long order will be triggered, the stop short order should be deleted
3. Use TP and SL for the Order

The current problem:
It seems like one order gets overwritten all the time. E.g. only long orders will be placed or short orders. It depends, which function I put first in the code. It does not work both ways.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
// This is the Entry
Minpreday = ta.valuewhen(SessionEnd,sessionLowPrice,0)
Maxpreday = ta.valuewhen(SessionEnd,sessionHighPrice,0)

// Define Stoploss = Midrange Box 
Stoploss = ((Maxpreday-Minpreday)/2) + Minpreday

// Define dynamic TP based on CRV
CRV_Faktor = input.float(title="CRV",minval=0, maxval=10, defval=1.0, step = 0.1)

float Tp_Long = 0.0
Tp_Long := ((Maxpreday - Stoploss)*CRV_Faktor)+Maxpreday


float Tp_Short = 0.0
Tp_Short := Minpreday-((Stoploss - Minpreday)*CRV_Faktor)

//Limit one Order per session

var entry_long_before = false
entry_long_before := sessionStart ? false : entry_long_before

var entry_short_before = false
entry_short_before := sessionStart ? false : entry_short_before

//Trading Session from X until Y
tradinghours = time(timeframe.period, "0745-1700", "UTC")
time_condition = FilterTradeTime ? not na(tradinghours) : true
bgcolor(not na(tradinghours) ? color.rgb(73, 196, 78, 90) : na)


if (inDateRange and time_condition and not entry_long_before and not entry_short_before)
    strategy.entry("Enter long", strategy.long, comment="entry long", stop=Maxpreday)
    entry_long_before := true
strategy.exit("Exit long", from_entry="Enter long", comment_profit = "TP Long", comment_loss = "SL Long", limit = Tp_Long, stop = Stoploss)
if (hour (23, "UTC"))
    strategy.close(id = "Enter long", comment = "Exit Time")
if not time_condition or entry_short_before 
    strategy.cancel("Enter long")


if (inDateRange and time_condition and not entry_short_before and not entry_long_before)
    strategy.entry("Enter short", strategy.short, comment="entry short", stop=Minpreday)
    entry_short_before := true
strategy.exit("Exit short", from_entry="Enter short", comment_profit = "TP Short", comment_loss = "SL Short", limit = Tp_Short, stop = Stoploss)
if (hour (23, "UTC"))
    strategy.close(id = "Enter short", comment = "Exit Time")
if not time_condition or entry_long_before
    strategy.cancel("Enter short")
```

Can somebody help me? I cannot spot my mistake?